# Display Woocommerce widgets on normal pages

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Is it possible to display woocommerce widgets on pages that are not part of Woocommerce?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably find a plugin to do this, but if you want to get your hands a little dirty you can do a bit of theme development work (you might want to do it as a child theme first though)

You can create a template page https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/

and then include a wigitised area on that page 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgetizing_Themes